# Topological characterization of closed surfaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

I am looking some reference, if it exist, that generalized the Moore`s characterization of the 2-sphere. To be more precise, Moore characterized 2-sphere by these two axioms: A space *X* is a 2-sphere if

1. *Jordan domain axiom*: For every simple closed curve *C*, the complement *X-C* consists of two connected components called *Jordan domains* bounded by *C*. Moreover, the boundary of Jordan domain bounded by *C* is exactly *C*.
2. *Basic axiom* There is a countable basis of topology in *X* consisting of Jordan domains.

I took this two axioms from the paper *Moore`s Theorem - V. Timorin*. In this same paper, the author says that *R.H. Bing* gave a strong version of this characterization: a compact, connected, locally connected Hausdorff space *X* with more than one point is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere, provide that no embedded $\mathbb{S}^0$ separates *X*, and all embedded $\mathbb{S}^1$ separate *X*.

My question is: Is there any such characterization for closed surfaces of genus *g*?

Comment: If you may apply Bing's characterization locally then you get a characterization of a surface. After this you may add something that distinguishes a surface of genus $g$. Say any $g$ disjoint circles separate while there are $g-1$ disjoint circles that do not separate.